# php how to get title url from id

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating PHP products view details page this script disaply like this URL
http://localhost/zblog/source.php?srcid=1 I want to get title URL from id
like this
http://localhost/zblog/source.php?title=some-title

Here is my code

```
   <?php
    include("config.php");
    if(isset($_GET['srcid'])) {
    $srcid = $_GET['title'];
    if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * from products WHERE srcid=?")){
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $srcid);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
    $result = $con->query($sql); 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){          
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

       }
     }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Exactly the same way but it depends on the type of search you want to do; exact or fuzzy?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is skewed, if the URL is:

```
http://localhost/zblog/source.php?srcid=1
```

then you aren't passing the title but if the URL like this:

```
http://localhost/zblog/source.php?title=some-title
```

then your `if` statement will never run because:

```
if(isset($_GET['srcid'])) {
```

it relies on `$_GET['srcid']`.

If you want to use the title then amend that if statement to look for `$_GET['title']` instead of `$_GET['srcid']` or, try passing both parameters in the URL together.

Comment: Changed what? Change with what?

Comment: isset srcid to title

Answer (score 0):

This would only work if your url included `?srcid=1&title=some-title`

This is because of your if statement which only runs if `srcid` is set.

change

```
if(isset($_GET['srcid'])) {
```

to

```
if(isset($_GET['title'])) {
```